# How to completely stop QTimer

Tags: c++, qt5

How could i completely stop a `QTimer` ? when i call `QTimer::stop()` it doesn't correctly stopped.

For example i create a `QTimer`:

```cpp
QTimer timer;
timer.singleShot(10000, this, [] { emit work_is_down(); });
```

and when i stopped:

```
timer.stop();
```

the lambda `[] { emit work_is_down(); }` is still run after 10000ms. how to completely stop it ?

Comment: I don't think you can do this with a single shot. singleShot is a static method and it does not even use the QTimer object.

Comment: In order to be able to cancel it, you need to do a little more boilerplate work that `singleShot()` saves you for simpler cases. In short, you'll need to connect to its `timeout()` signal. Then if you call `stop()`, it won't timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QTimer::singleShot` is a `static` method of the `QTimer` class. You can call it on an instance but it will be fundamentally disconnected from that instance.

You need to do the full QTimer dance, as said in the comments above:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer();
QObject::connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [](){ emit work_is_down(); });
timer->setSingleShot(true);
timer->start(10000);
```

Don't forget to call `delete timer` or `timer->deleteLater()` when you're done with it, or better yet, use a `std::unique_ptr` or `QSharedPointer`.